# Can I see failed SQL queries text?

Tags: sql-server, query

I added some triggers to third party DB and now the third party application failed to run.

Is there a way to see the failed queries?

for example:

I run:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1  --query succeeded
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ  --query failed since table doesn't exist.
```

I can see succeeded queries by running the following:

```
SELECT st.last_execution_time, t.text FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stat AS st 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(st.sql_handle) AS t
WHERE t.text LIKE 'SELECT * FROM %'
```

I'm looking for a similar query in manner to shows the failures.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider creating an extended event trace including the `error_reported` event filtered on `severity > 10`.

Comment: See [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7416373/447514)